# Python plotly Dash updating/refreshing layout

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have app that imports `layout` from second module then renders it in tab as returning `app.layout` to this tab content. I have problem with thing that layout is imported with default values of inputs and when I have inputs filled with keys and change between tabs then when I click back to the inputs tab the values reset to default 'x'. I managed to solve this problem by declaring layout second time in a callback but it doesn't look good and would require to write layout 2 times for further functionalities. There is my code:

```
if 'manager' not in vars():
    manager = Recognition('xx', 'xx')
    print('defining manager')

lcheck = 0
while lcheck == 0:
    layout = [
        html.Div([
            html.Div(
                [
                    html.H3("Primary API key"),
                    dcc.Input(
                        id='primary-key',
                        value=manager.api_key,
                        placeholder='Enter a value...',
                        type='text',
                        style = {"width":"50%"}
                    ),
                    html.H3("Private API key"),
                    dcc.Input(
                        id='private-key',
                        value=manager.api_secret,
                        placeholder='Enter a value...',
                        type='text',
                        style = {"width":"50%"}
                    ),


                ],
            ),
            html.Button('Submit', id='button', className='btn btn-primary'),
            html.Div(id='output-hidden')
        ])
    ]
    lcheck=1


@app.callback(
    Output('primary-key', 'value'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('primary-key', 'value'), 
     State('private-key', 'value')]
)
def update_output(n_clicks, value1, value2):
    values = {'value1':value1, 'value2':value2}
    global manager
    global layout
    manager.update(value1, value2)
    layout = [
        html.Div([
            html.Div(
                [
                    html.H3("Primary API key"),
                    dcc.Input(
                        id='primary-key',
                        value=manager.api_key,
                        placeholder='Enter a value...',
                        type='text',
                        style = {"width":"50%"}
                    ),
                    html.H3("Private API key"),
                    dcc.Input(
                        id='private-key',
                        value=manager.api_secret,
                        placeholder='Enter a value...',
                        type='text',
                        style = {"width":"50%"}
                    ),


                ],
            ),
            html.Button('Submit', id='button', className='btn btn-primary'),
            html.Div(id='output-hidden')
        ])
    ]

    lcheck=0
    return values['value1']
```

As you can see it saves new layout everytime I send new data with button but this solution looks terrible I would like to find better solution without chaos in code. Whole thing is to update `value=manager.api_key,` and `value=manager.api_secret,` in layout variable. I was thinking to get access of the values like from normal `list` but it is not possible since it is not nested as regular list. Is there any way to access the values for example `layout.getid("primary-key").value` or something like this? How to clean this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this problem. As my app us rendering `app.layout` everytime I select a tab, so it always render the `layout` that was assigned during first import. Firstly I wanted to override layout everytime in a callback function but it has no sense to write `layout=` 2 times. So I found in dash `docs` a `dash core component` named `dcc.Store` (it stores json in hidden div). I used it like this:

```
html.Div([
        dcc.Store(id='storage')
    ],
            id="hiddendata",
            style={"display": "none"},
    ),
```

This div is placed directly after 'Tabs' div and is there as a 'cache' memory for tabs to remember previous state. And finally I have updated callbacks to change data in `dcc.Store` everytime I send new keys so when I leave the tab, other tabs know what is there:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('storage', 'data'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('primary-key', 'value'), 
     State('private-key', 'value')]
)
def update_output(n_clicks, value1, value2):
    values = {'value1':value1, 'value2':value2}
    global manager
    global layout
    manager.update(value1, value2)
    lcheck=0
    return values

@app.callback(
    Output('primary-key', 'value'),
    [Input('storage', 'data')],
    [State('storage', 'data')])
def update_values(values, value):
    if values:
        return value['value1']

@app.callback(
    Output('private-key', 'value'),
    [Input('storage', 'data')],
    [State('storage', 'data')])
def update_values(values, value):
    if values:
        return value['value2']
```

Comment: Why do you call ``storage`` the way you did:    ```[Input('storage', 'data')],
    [State('storage', 'data')])``` ?  If the storage changes the callback will be called and you can access `data` via Input. why do you need State in addition? I think this is redundant.